# Global variable incrementing in child process but down decrease in parent

Tags: c, process, fork

Working on a consumer producer problem.
During testing i'm having issues with decrementing the globar variable buffcount1
I threw in a print statment to see if the parent loop is functioning and it is but the problem is the value dont decrement

```
int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        close(fds[0]);
        while(1){
            
            if(buffcount1 != MAX){
                sem_wait(&empty);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
                write(fds[1], &count2, sizeof(count2));
                count1++;
                buffcount1++;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
                usleep(((rand() % 5) + 1) * 10000);
                printf("count1: %d\t buffcount1: %d\n", count1, buffcount1);
                 sem_post(&full);
            }
            
            
        }
    } else{
        while(1){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            buffcount1--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
            usleep(((rand() % 5) + 1) * 20000);       
        }
    
    }
```

Tried doing it with and without the mutex among other things but nothing works

Comment: Forked processes don't share their memory.  Each process has its own copy of `buffcount1` (and `lock1` for that mattter) which are entirely independent of each other.  If you want to be able to share variables, you want to be using threads (e.g. `pthread_create`) not processes, or else shared memory.

Comment: And what is the write to `fds[1]` supposed to accomplish?  Presumably this is one side of a pipe, but nobody is reading the other side.

Comment: thanks for the input i'll make the necessary changes @Nate Eldredge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question sounds like you just wanted a basic example of a producer that increments a value, and a consumer that decrements a value with a cycle counter.

There are a few things to point out here. First is that you're using `fork()` which creates a new process, not a new thread. The two processes would no longer be sharing memory, so both your mutex and semaphore functions are not looking at the same things. What you might be looking for instead is to create pthreads. Here's a simple example of a producer and consumer thread, where the producer increments a work counter and a cycle counter, and the consumer decrements the work counter. Both stop working when the cycle counter gets to 10.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct work
{
    int cycleCount;
    int workCount;
    sem_t lock;
};

void *producer(void *ptr)
{
    struct work *data = (struct work *)ptr;
    int working = 1;
    while (working)
    {
        sem_wait(&data->lock);
        data->workCount++;
        data->cycleCount++;

        if (data->cycleCount == 10)
        {
            working = 0;
        }
        sem_post(&data->lock);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *consumer(void *ptr)
{
    struct work *data = (struct work *)ptr;
    int working = 1;
    while (working)
    {
        sem_wait(&data->lock);
        data->workCount--;

        if (data->cycleCount == 10 && data->workCount == 0)
        {
            working = 0;
        }
        sem_post(&data->lock);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t prod;
    pthread_t cons;
    int prodRet = 0;
    int prodCon = 0;

    struct work data;
    sem_init(&data.lock, 0, 1);
    data.cycleCount = 0;
    data.workCount = 0;

    pthread_create(&prod, 0, producer, (void *)&data);
    pthread_create(&cons, 0, consumer, (void *)&data);

    pthread_join(prod, (void *)&prodRet);
    pthread_join(cons, (void *)&prodCon);

    printf("cycleCount: %d  ;  workCount: %d\n", data.cycleCount, data.workCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, in main, we init a semaphore, and then `pthread_create` two threads, one producer, and one consumer. We give them both the same work struct as an argument, and both operate on the work struct, using the lock to synchronize access to the work and cycle counters.